# How to merge two dataframes that have common values but without common columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two dataframes that are imported CSV files

df1:

```
1, 204c, 204s
2, 205c, 205s
3, ..., ...
```

df2:

```
204c, 1000
205c, 3000
..., ...
..., ...
204s, 4000
205s, 5000
```

I would like to combine df2 into df1 based off of their 'c' and 'd' values at the end so it can look something like this

df3:

```
204c, 1000, 204s, 4000
205c, 3000, 205c, 5000
```

I believe it had to do with pandas.concat(), .merge() or .join() however I am a bit stuck on the correct one to use.

I have tried using df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'cross') and it did every iteration of merge for each value which was incorrect and i have tried df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1) which was closer but it did not take the 's' values into consideration and put it into NaN categories

Comment: I would chain two `.merge` commands together, one for each relevant column in df1

Comment: Which merge commands in particular? since there are no common keys/columns I do not know which to specify before doing the double join

Comment: You should read the docstring for .merge. You don’t need common columns. You can specify the left and right join keys separately

Comment: something like `a = df1.merge(df2, left_on=0, right_on=0)` and `b = df1.merge(df2, left_on=1, right_on=0)` and then join `a` and `b`

Comment: you should be careful about the leading spaces when reading those CSVs, or else the merging won't work properly

Comment: Figured it out, it was a left_on and right_on command, as suggested by tdy 
thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic approach that can handle any number of columns to be mapped:

```
f1 = '''1, 204c, 204s
2, 205c, 205s'''

f2 = '''204c, 1000
205c, 3000
204s, 4000
205s, 5000
'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(f1), sep=r',\s*', engine='python', header=None, index_col=0)

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(f2), sep=r',\s*', engine='python', header=None, names=['val', 'val2'])

tmp = df1.stack().to_frame(name='val')

out = (tmp.merge(df2, how='left')
          .set_axis(tmp.index)
          .unstack()
          .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, kind='stable', sort_remaining=False)
       )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    val  val2   val  val2
      1     1     2     2
0                        
1  204c  1000  204s  4000
2  205c  3000  205s  5000
```